# Is it possible to force a country code on messages which automatically sent via apps?

Tags: sms, international-prefix

I am trying to use an application which requires me to send a message to its service from my phone number. The service is in a different country than where I am so the messages are being sent to the wrong number. I am trying to get these messages to be sent to the correct country. I don't have any ways of changing this through the app.

Would there be a setting or a 3rd party app which can force a country code on all messages being sent?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you clarify the exact steps of what the application is doing, like how the app sets the number, just in case it may help? As of current writing, Rohit's answer is correct in general, without knowing the details of the app.

Comment: So in the app, there’s a button to start the signup process and that’s about it from the input part. The app has the permissions to send messages. When that button is clicked it automatically sends the message to a random number which keeps changing. 

The SIM card in the phone is of country X and the sms also needs to go to the country code X. The phone itself is in country Y and therefore I am having the country code issue. The message is going to country Y and I’m trying see if I can make it go to country X

Answer (score 1):

No, a 3rd party app cant change another app like that, nor the server's code thats actually processing the requests. Try contacting support.

Comment: I understand that one app can't change the other's functionality. I was wondering whether there can be a setting which a 3rd party app can change within the phone for the country codes to be forced.

Comment: @ShubhSheth the usual workaround is to add the country prefix directly on the contacts, but without knowing how that specific app works, it seems impossible to achieve what you want.